# SCSS - Loop a list starting at key 2

Tags: css, sass

If I have a list as follows:

```
$breakpoints: (
  all: all,
  xl: 1200,
  lg: 1037,
  md: 797,
  sm: 615,
  xs: 415,
);
```

In an `@each` is there any way to loop through the list but either first remove the first key, or start at key 2?

Comment: Were the answers you've received useful ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser not had a chance to test yet. Will be getting back to this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first entry using map-remove (note I added * 1px) to get unit values :)

*This will not mutate the $breakpoints map*

```
@each $key, $value in map-remove($breakpoints, all) {
    @media (max-width: $value * 1px){
        // dummy content printing out the breakpoint
        body::before { content: '#{$key}' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to achieve that.

### 1. With a @each loop

In this loop, I'll check if the value is equal to "all", if it is, I'll do nothing and continue my loop.
It works well, but if you decide to change "all" with some other name, you'll need to update the loop.

```
@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
  @if ($value == "all") {} // If the value == all, do nothing
  @else {
    @media screen and (max-width: $value) {
      /* Your fancy code */
    }
  }
}
```

### 2. With a @for loop

In this loop, I'll go through the length of $breakpoints starting from 2.
Then, I'll retrieve the value according to the index.

```
@for $i from 2 through (length($breakpoints)) {
    $breakpoint : nth($breakpoints, $i);
    $value : nth($breakpoint, 2);
    @media screen and (max-width: $value) {
      /* Your fancy code */
    }
}
```

### EDIT

**It can be even easier with the @each loop:**

```
@each $key, $value in $breakpoints {
  $i: index($breakpoints, $key $value);
  @if ($i != 1)
  {
    @media screen and (max-width: $value) {
      /* Your fancy code */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can do that. I'd suggest keeping two lists, one containing the values you want to iterate over, and another that joins the "all" value and the first list.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list